# How to fill hole in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

I am modifying a 3D scanned model
, I want to join the upper and lower parts of the shoe.

I didn't know how to do it in sculpt mode, so I did a merged the vertex in edit mode, but it didn't work. (Please refer to the image)

Also, I found an article asking the same question.
https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-fill-the-holes-and-avoid-overlaps-in-sculpt-mode/641648

Is this impossible even as of 2021 without using add-ons?

I'm new to 3D scanning and sculpting, and I'm sorry if it's a rudimentary question.

[image]

Comment: Why even using sculpt mode to fill holes in a mesh object? It's not meant for that. There are automatic tools (mesh clean-up > fill holes) which don't always do a good job, there are manual tools (selecting vertices and moving / snapping them), there are different programs like Meshlab which have more serious toolset for that

Comment: Thanks for a reply! I tried to use fill hole tool, but it did not work. And about snapping tool : I couldn't come up with the idea! I will try it!  Also thank you for telling me about the existence of Meshlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do it is joining the necessary parts and then remeshing it using voxel remesh option. The model will become one piece. So if you have large holes or things that are separated - just join them Ctrl+J and remesh.

Comment: thank you so much !